# In this function why is "ho" printed first instead of "hello"

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
function init() {
    console.log("hello " + validate());
}
function validate() {
    console.log("ho ");
    return 'hi'
}
init()
```

The output of this code is:

```
ho
hello hi
```

I can't make sense of the order. What am I missing?

Comment: The `validate` function will output his `console.log` before returning his value to the `init` `console`

Comment: Just to elaborate a little bit further on 0stone0s answer: when `init()` is executed, its `console.log()` statement is processed. In that process `validate()` is of course executed. This causes to first `console.log()` the `ho` and then `hello hi`.

Comment: `init()` was called on load. `init` called `validate` from console.log. `validate` printed `ho` and returned `hi`. Which was printed in `init` along with `hello` together as `hello hi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to show the 'order of operations'

1. Call `init()`
2. `init()` will `console.log`, but needs the result of `validate()` to do so
3. `validate()` is called
4. `validate()` outputs `ho` using `console.log`
5. `validate()` returns `hi` to `init`
6. `init()` will now `console.log` the complete string

```
ho             <-- Result of validate() being called to get value in init
hello hi       <-- Result of init()` console.log
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to create the string to output in `init()`, the function `validate()` is called first. It completes its logic (including outputting "ho") until it hits a return statement. After it returns "hi", the strings are concatenated to result in "hello hi" and just then are they printed to the console.

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing this answer using very minimum technical terms for you to understand. If you are interested more on how code executes, i recommend that you read about stacks (not the data structure) and frames

```
01 | function init() {
02 |     console.log("hello " + validate());
03 | }
04 | function validate() {
05 |     console.log("ho ");
06 |     return 'hi'
07 | }
08 | init()
```

This is how your code gets executed. The entry point is at line 8, because all the other lines before that are part of function declarations. So `init()` is called. which makes the computer to execute the function in line 1.

in there you ask to `console.log` the string `hello` and whats returned from function `validate()`.

now the computer starts executing the `validate()` function because to complete the `console.log` you requested in line 2 requires the return of `validate()`. Inside `validate()` function you say ask to `console.log` the string `ho` . Therefore `ho`  is printed. Then in line 6 you return the string `hi`.

great. now you have everything you need to finish executing the line 2. So it concat `"hello "` and `"hi"` (which was returned from the `validate()` function. the result is `"hello hi"`. Then the computer prints it. But remember you already print the word `"ho "` at line 5. therefore after executing line 2, the terminal should display `"ho hello hi"`

Answer (score 1):

The execution is as follows

- `init` was called on load.
- `init` called `validate` from `console.log`.
- `validate` printed `ho` and returned `hi`.
- This return value was accepted in `init` method, which was printed in `init` along with `hello` together as `hello hi`
- So first printin value will be `ho` from `validate` function there after `hello hi` from `init` function.

Answer (score 1):

There is a call stack mechanism maintained by the engine to manage the execution contexts for different functions. Call stack follows a Last In First Out order of processing.
The init() function is placed in the call stack as it is called first.
Then validate() function is encountered and it is placed on the stack.

At this point, Call stack will be like:

- validate
- init

While executing the calls, the last entry ie. validate() is popped from the stack and prints 'ho' first.

Then init() is executed which prints out 'hello hi'

Check the link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Call_stack
for more details.

Hope this was helpful.